# Swift - UIButton image size depending on font size

Tags: swift, uibutton, resize

I'm trying to create a UIButton with an image in it (swift 4, xcode 10). When I add an icon like that :

```
let ftitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string:" Retry",attributes: [

        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Italic", size:50 )!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white
])

buttonRetry.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_refresh"), for: .normal)
buttonRetry.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
buttonRetry.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
buttonRetry.setAttributedTitle(ftitle, for: .normal)
```

The icon button is always at the same size (26 x 26). When I change the font size to 10 for exemple, the icon does not fit. I tried this just after the code above:

```
buttonRetry.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

But I does not work neither. I also tried to set the UIButton frame at a certain height, at the beginning of the above code but still no effect.. No effect also when I change the UIImageView frame. The image view looks stucked in this arbitrary size (26x26) whatever I can do .

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using an attributed string anyway?

Comment: Just to set custom font size:)

Comment: Try using `buttonRetry.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Italic", size:50)`. And simply set the text, you don't need to use an attributed string just to set a custom font!

Comment: It’s still doesn’t work when I try that..

Comment: The image size still stucks to 26x26. I don’t understand why contentMode = .scaleAspectFit doesnt make it since it’s exactly what this attribute is for : scale the view to the parent size